# No Networking Lubuntu 14.04 on iMac G5 PowerPC

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, mac, powerpc

Have just completed a fresh install of Lubuntu 14.04 on my iMac G5, but I can't seem to get any networking. Neither wireless or wired internet seems to work, the network manager can't find any available networks. Have already tried restarting the network manager applet, but to no avail. Any ideas?

**Edit**: As requested, my output for `lspci -nnk | grep -e 0280 -e 0200 -A2` is:

```
0001:01:01.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:4318]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge

0001:03:0f.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Apple Inc. Shasta (Sun GEM) [106b:0051]
    Kernel driver in use: gem
```

The `0280` and `0200` are both in red

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep -e 0280 -e 0200 -A2`

Comment: Edited to include the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wireless device requires proprietary firmware. However, without ethernet and therefor internet access, we will have to get the firmware off-line. Please download the b43.zip package on some other computer and transfer it on a USB key or similar to the Ubuntu computer's desktop: http://ubuntuforums.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=229272&d=1356748832

Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now, in the terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43
sudo cp ~/Desktop/b43/* /lib/firmware/b43
```

Reboot and the wireless should be working.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much! Any idea what I could do about the ethernet?

Comment: Any clues in the message log? `dmesg | grep -e gem -e eth` I've never even heard of the ethernet module *gem* so this should be fun for both of us!

Comment: Ok, so our output is:

    `[  27.267086] gem 0001:03:0f.0 eth0: GMAC PHY not responding !
    [  27.704547] gem 0001:03:0f.0 eth0: Found no PHY
    [  28.045500] IPv6: ADDRCONF(METDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready`

Comment: This might also be some insight as to what the module is: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man4/if_gem.4freebsd.html

Comment: Could you please try the live DVD or USB for Ubuntu 16.04 and check if the error persists? In 16.04, the module is named *sungem* and presumably newer! I have been unable to Google a fix for "GMAC PHY not responding."

Comment: I'll have to use the Lubuntu USB rather than regular Ubuntu, it doesn't have support for PowerPC otherwise. Past midnight here, so I'll give that a try tomorrow after work and report back! :)

Comment: Ok, just booted up with the Lubuntu 16.04 Live USB, and the ethernet still doesn't work. Seems like much the same issue

Comment: Are there clues in the message log while booted into 16.04? `dmesg | grep gem`

Comment: Much the same as before: `[   11.074447] sungem.c:v1.0 David S. Miller <davem@redhat.com>  [   11.076974] gem 0001:03:0f.0 eth0: Sun GEM (PCI) 10/100/1000BaseT Ethernet 00:0d:93:7b:8c:28  [   11.682142] gem 0001:03:0f.0 enP1p3s15f0: renamed from eth0  [   37.272739] gem 0001:03:0f.0 enP1p3s15f0: GMAC PHY not responding !  [   37.709271] gem 0001:03:0f.0 enP1p3s15f0: Found no PHY`

Comment: Let's also see: `dmesg | grep -i enP1` I am not encouraged so far.

Comment: I'll post that up when I get access to the machine again tomorrow. Is it possible that there is just an underlying problem with the adapter itself, that it might just be dead? Considering it's a ~10 year old machine at this point

Comment: It is possible. You might also check: `dmesg | grep 03:0f` If you can simply use the wireless, you might just enjoy it as is.

Comment: Result of `dmesg | grep -i enP1`is `[   11.704363] gem 0001:03:0f.0 enP1p3s15f0: renamed from eth0
[   37.222059] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enP1p3s15f0: link is not ready
[   37.364981] gem 0001:03:0f.0 enP1p3s15f0: GMAC PHY not responding !
[   37.801522] gem 0001:03:0f.0 enP1p3s15f0: Found no PHY
[   38.709091] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enP1p3s15f0: link is not ready`

Comment: Result of `dmesg | grep 03:0f` is `[    0.160399] pci 0001:03:0f.0: [106b:0051] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.160414] pci 0001:03:0f.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x80400000-0x805fffff]
[    0.160445] pci 0001:03:0f.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0x80200000-0x802fffff pref]
[   11.087721] gem 0001:03:0f.0 eth0: Sun GEM (PCI) 10/100/1000BaseT Ethernet 00:0d:93:7b:8c:28
[   11.704363] gem 0001:03:0f.0 enP1p3s15f0: renamed from eth0
[   37.364981] gem 0001:03:0f.0 enP1p3s15f0: GMAC PHY not responding !
[   37.801522] gem 0001:03:0f.0 enP1p3s15f0: Found no PHY`

Comment: I see nothing informative here, except: `enP1p3s15f0: GMAC PHY not responding ! [ 37.801522] gem 0001:03:0f.0 enP1p3s15f0: Found no PHY` which suggests that the hardware is defective.  I'd simply use the wireless, or if ethernet is required, I'd look into any of a number of USB-to-ethernet adapters. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah I was getting that impression too... Its ok, I found a USB/ethernet adapter, so I'll give that a try. Thanks so much for helping out through all of this!